# Deploying C-dependent Perl libraries

Tags: perl, ncurses, curses

I have an application that I deploy on both Linux (Red Hat) and Unix (Solaris). My application installs itself using the built in Perl, and from then creates its own local Perl (new user).

I would like to know what is the best way to deploy [`Curses::UI`](http://search.cpan.org/~mdxi/Curses-UI-0.9609/lib/Curses/UI.pm)? Currently I install other modules by just copying them to my local perl `lib` folder, but these are pure Perl modules that don't depend on C libraries (.so shared objects, XS, etc.).

Also will I have to compile `libncurses` for each platform beforehand?

**NOTE:** The computer doesnt have network connectivity, hence I cant use the CPAN module.

Comment: No network, no problem. Make a [minicpan](http://p3rl.org/minicpan) copy and carry it over to the target. Configure its CPAN client to [read from the local filesystem](http://p3rl.org/CPAN#The-urllist-parameter-has-CD-ROM-support) instead of the network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a CPAN client (CPAN.pm, CPANPLUS) to deploy modules such as Curses::UI from CPAN. Usually you need development libs to compile XS modules. For Curses::UI the Ubuntu package is called `libncurses-dev`. Other Linux distributions probably have an ncurses devel package under the same or similar name.

You said you have a local Perl lib. A very good way to have a local lib is the module of the same name - [local::lib](http://p3rl.org/local%3a%3alib). Its documentation will tell you how to easily install modules into your local::lib using a CPAN client.

Comment: so can I use CPAN::Mini to build a local repository which consists only of Curses::UI and its dependencies?

Answer (score 1):

For the CPAN modules that need to be built, try looking at [carton](https://metacpan.org/module/carton). It has a bundle command that will bundle all your cpan modules together so they can be installed/built on the target machines without any network involved.

As for libcurses, I'd probably lean toward having a custom installer to build it on the target machine if it's not already installed. That or make your software refuse to be installed unless that library is found. Unfortunately I don't know of a good way to build dependent C libraries locally other than doing a custom build script.